# Crystal Reports for Visual Studio 2012 install error

Tags: visual-studio, asp-classic, visual-studio-2012

I have tried installing Crystal Reports for VS2012 and it fails out every time with this error. Has anyone else encountered this? To be honest the whole CR/VS2012 thing is a pain, I've always used 2010 and never had any issues. Any and all help is appreciated. Thanks.

Error 1327. Invalid Drive: O:\

Comment: CR for VS2010 came out some time after VS2010. Until then there were issues. Can't say about 2012, but just an FYI

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when I wanted to install Dreamweaver 5.5 and found the solution [here](http://www.techsupportforum.com/forums/f19/error-1327-invalid-drive-e-424437.html)